# Update table with multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am not really a SQL guy so any help would be appreciated. I am trying to update a table when fields match on one column and do not on another:

```
UPDATE dleads
SET mag_name = magazines.mag_name
FROM magazines
WHERE dleads.umc = magazines.umc and
dleads.mag_name <> magazines.mag_name
```

I can get the `SELECT` to work, but not the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Everything looks OK. Are you getting any errors? What does you SELECT query look like that returns records? Do you get more than one record back per `dleads.mag_name`?

Comment: Your query should work.  Please elaborate on what "not working" really means.

Comment: [SO do you have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not robust in handling NULL values.

You could use this instead:

UPDATE dleads SET mag_name = magazines.mag_name FROM magazines WHERE dleads.umc = magazines.umc AND COALESCE(dleads.mag_name, '') <> COALESCE(magazines.mag_name, '');

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like it's doing exactly what you describe:

```
UPDATE dleads d
SET    mag_name = m.mag_name
FROM   magazines m
WHERE  d.umc = m.umc
AND    d.mag_name <> m.mag_name;
```

The most common thing being overlooked here would be **NULL** values. If `mag_name` can be NULL in either table, and you want to update anyway, use the NULL-safe [**`IS DISTINCT FROM`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html):

```
UPDATE dleads d
SET    mag_name = m.mag_name
FROM   magazines m
WHERE  d.umc = m.umc
AND    d.mag_name IS DISTINCT FROM m.mag_name;
```

Aside: You mention "multiple joins" in the title, but I only see a *single* join in your query.